# can Hibernate emit MERGE SQL statements for INSERT/UPDATE constructs?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Here I'm referring to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28SQL%29

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8553030/304690 offers even a wider list of databases supporting MERGE SQL statement.

http://hibernate.org/docs do not seem to offer references to MERGE.

Is there some way to write entities or configure Hibernate for MERGE statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is `session.merge()` which does basicly the same using standard sql selects to determine if it is there or not. It has therefor 2 roundtrips but is supported across all sqldatabases.

Comment: Would SQL dialects http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-dialects allow database specific overrides?

Comment: i don't think so. this feature is the same for all dialects. Hibernate already uses the id or version to determine if it needs insert or Update. any other conditions are possibly openended to have them as out of the box feature